How to exchange information between Taipy page after a clic on a page
I have two pages in my main.py
pages = {
    "/": root_md,
    "Page-MAP": page1_md,
    "Page-DASHBOARD": page2_md,
}

With the variable variable_main = "station1" define in main.py
How can I, after a clic on my Page-MAP, receive an information, a variable on my Page-DASHBOARD redirection?
The objectif is to update my page DASHBOARD  after a clic on an other page MAP.
Clic on my Page-MAP:
def on_change(state, var_name, var_value):
    state['Page-MAP'].variable_main = "station 2"
    navigate(state, to='Page-DASHBOARD')

I want on my DASHBOARD page change the station_name according to the clic in my page MAP.
DASHBOARD page:
<|toggle|theme|>
<|layout|columns=1 2 2 2|gap=40px|class_name=card|
<|{image_path}|image|>
### Name: **<|{station_name}|text|raw|>**{: .color-primary}
|>


Could you elaborate? Maybe, create a simple version of what you would like.

I want to transmit data between pages. How can I pass information from one Taipy page to another?

Variables/data can be accessed by every page. It is common for every page if you define your variables in your main.py and if you have page scopes, you can access data from other pages with state['your_page'].your_variable. I am providing a general answer here; this is why it would be better if you provide your example

I have updated my question with an example

I guess variable_main is the same as station_name in your example.
If it is a global variable, there is no need to define the page scope.
def on_change(state, var_name, var_value):
    state.variable_main = "station 2"
    navigate(state, to='Page-DASHBOARD')

And you should change station_name to variable_main in your DASHBOARD page:
...
### Name: **<|{variable_main}|text|raw|>**{: .color-primary}


Does it fix your issue?

yes, thank you foyour help
